# Real path of ZF2's public directory

Tags: php, plugins, file-io, controller, zend-framework2

I would like to write some data (from a custom controller plugin) into files under the 'messages' subdirectory of my website's public directory.

The custom controller plugin is quite simple:

```
<?php

namespace Main\Service;

class MessageWriter
{    
    public $data = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function write_message()
    {
        $this->time = time();
        $data = serialize($this->data);

        $filename = time() . '_' . rand(1000, 9999);
        @file_put_contents('/var/www/public/messages/' . $filename, $data);
    }

}

?>
```

I have two tiny problems / questions:

1. How can i avoid the hardcoding of the path? Isn't there a ZF2 config variable which holds the real path of the public directory (/var/www/public).
2. Is there any class for writing files in ZF2, or it's OK using file_put_contents and similar file functions?

Thank you very much!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZF2, all paths are relative to the application root, so you should be able to use `file_put_contents('public/messages/' . $filename, $data)`. And `file_put_contents()` is fine to use.

Comment: This all paths are relative thing is good, until i don't have to use it too much. Imagine that you have to hardcode the name of the public directory (in this case: public) in several plugins, controllers (writing, opening files, checking whether a file exists etc.). Then - for some reason - you have to change it for example from public to public_new. So you must change the hardcoded values everywhere, the code will be less portable etc. It would be great to have some global config variable for holding the name of the public directory.

Comment: If you wanted to go down that route, rather than having some global config for the public folder, I'd add a config path for messages which you could then inject into your MessageWriter service.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/messages/'.$filename
```

Edit: just realised this is zf2 not zf1...

Everything is relative to the application path in ZF2